# Loss is not changing over epochs

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to train RNN (pytorch) on the domain generated domain-names data with binary classification.

`m644136d0.tmodns.ne | 0`

`dfg.ca.gov | 0`

`c4w6wpg81xsbopy8a67.ddns.net | 1`

Where 1 is generated domain name
I'm using one-hot embeddings for the domain name
The RNN definition is next :

```
import torch.nn as nn

class rnnModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, num_hid_neurons, num_out, nun_hid_layers=1):
        super(rnnModel, self).__init__()
             
        self.nn = nn.RNN(embedding_dim, num_hid_neurons, nun_hid_layers, batch_first=True)
        
        # Fully connected layer
        self.fc = nn.Linear(num_hid_neurons, 2)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        self.num_out = num_out
        self.nun_hid_layers = nun_hid_layers
        self.num_hid_neurons = num_hid_neurons

    # define the forward function
    def forward(self, input, hidden):
        if hidden == None :
            batch_size = input.size(0)
            hidden = self.init_hidden(batch_size)

        output, hidden = self.nn(input, hidden)
        output = self.fc(output)
        output = self.softmax(output)
        return output, hidden
        
    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        # This method generates the first hidden state of zeros which we'll use in the forward pass
        hidden = torch.zeros(self.nun_hid_layers, batch_size, self.num_hid_neurons)
        return hidden
```

Model instance :

```
n_hidden = 256

model = rnnModel(vocab_size=vocab_size, embedding_dim=dict_size, num_hid_neurons=n_hidden, num_out=2, nun_hid_layers=2)

n_epochs = 50
lr=1e-5

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
```

Dataset preparation:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torch.nn.functional as F

df = pd.read_csv('training.csv', header=None, names=['domain', 'dga'])

domains = df.domain.tolist()

vocab = sorted(list(set(''.join(domains))))
vocab_size = len(vocab)

# function to convert a domain name to tokens represented as one-hot vectors 

def domain2tensor(domain):
    tensor = torch.zeros(len(domain), 1, vocab_size)
    for i, c in enumerate(domain):
        tensor[ i, 0, char2token[c] ] = 1
    return tensor

class DGADataSet(Dataset) :
    def __init__(self, dataframe, padded_size):
        self.padded_size = padded_size
        self.Xtr = dataframe["domain"]
        self.ytr = dataframe["dga"]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.Xtr)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index) :
        temp_text = self.Xtr.iloc[index]
        not_padded = domain2tensor(temp_text)
        padded = F.pad(not_padded, pad=(0,0,0,0,self.padded_size-len(not_padded),0))
        x = self.ytr.iloc[index]
        return padded, torch.Tensor([float(x), float(1-x)])
```

And training is that:

```
batch_size = 100
dataset = DGADataSet(df, maxlen)
train_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size, shuffle=True)
losses = []
for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    for input, target in train_data_loader :
        hidden = None
        for i in range(input.size(1)):
            x = input[:,i,:,:]
            output, hidden = model(x, hidden) 
        
        output = output.view(-1, 2)
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
    losses.append(loss.item())
    print('Epoch: {}/{}.............'.format(epoch, n_epochs), end=' ')
    print("Loss: {:.4f}".format(loss.item()))
```

And over 50 epochs the loss is not changing, Loss: 0.6931

Please advise what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks !!!

Comment: Sounds like it is stuck in a local minima. Have you provided a complete working example? What's the dataset? Your description leaves a lot to the imagination. In general when the loss function doesn't change, then it isn't improving.

Comment: @matt I added dataset preparation. The example is working. I don't know how to solve that issue. Tried different learning rates, and all other hyperparams. Nothing helps. Thanks

Comment: What does "the example is working" mean? I cannot run your code, I get `NameError: name 'vocab_size' is not defined` . You should inspect your inputs and outputs. Either your problem is poorly defined and you just cannot train a neural network, or there is something wrong with your data.

Comment: @matt Sorry, for confusing you. I put here the notebook and training data : https://github.com/slavag/RNN-Learn   , Thanks